# Building OpenJDK 9 on Mac os

Tags: java, macos

I encountered these problems when I building openjdk9

Building target 'default (exploded-image)' in configuration 'macosx- 
 x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug'
 Warning: No mercurial configuration present and no .src-rev

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0x000000010394aca8, pid=13189, tid=8451
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (9.0.4) (slowdebug build 

9.0.4-internal+0-adhoc.apple.jdk9u)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (slowdebug 9.0.4-internal+0-adhoc.apple.jdk9u, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, serial gc, bsd-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.dylib+0xd4aca8]  PerfData::~PerfData()+0x8
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/apple/SourceCode/jdk9u/make/hs_err_pid13189.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

[error occurred during error reporting (), id 0x4]

make[3]: *** [/Users/apple/SourceCode/jdk9u/build/macosx-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/jdk/_packages_attribute.done] Abort trap: 6
make[2]: *** [exploded-image-optimize] Error 2

ERROR: Build failed for target 'default (exploded-image)' in configuration 'macosx-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug' (exit code 2) 

No indication of failed target found.
Hint: Try searching the build log for '] Error'.
Hint: See common/doc/building.html#troubleshooting for assistance.

make[1]: *** [main] Error 2
make: *** [default] Error
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem.

You just need comment out this：

```
hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/perfMemory.cpp

// if (SafepointSynchronize::is_at_safepoint() && !StatSampler::is_active()) {
//  PerfDataManager::destroy();
// }
```

That's ok. But maybe memory leak when use jstat to monitor jvm.