# build openjdk9 on macos and crash

Tags: java, build, jvm, java-9

I encountered these problems when I building openjdk9.

```
os:       macos high sierra(10.13.5)
xcode：   9.4
freetype: 2.9.1
```

I encountered these problems when I building openjdk9

Building target 'default (exploded-image)' in configuration 'macosx- 
 x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug'
 Warning: No mercurial configuration present and no .src-rev

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0x000000010394aca8, pid=13189, tid=8451
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (9.0.4) (slowdebug build 

9.0.4-internal+0-adhoc.apple.jdk9u)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (slowdebug 9.0.4-internal+0-adhoc.apple.jdk9u, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, serial gc, bsd-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.dylib+0xd4aca8]  PerfData::~PerfData()+0x8
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/apple/SourceCode/jdk9u/make/hs_err_pid13189.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

[error occurred during error reporting (), id 0x4]

make[3]: *** [/Users/apple/SourceCode/jdk9u/build/macosx-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/jdk/_packages_attribute.done] Abort trap: 6
make[2]: *** [exploded-image-optimize] Error 2

ERROR: Build failed for target 'default (exploded-image)' in configuration 'macosx-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug' (exit code 2) 

No indication of failed target found.
Hint: Try searching the build log for '] Error'.
Hint: See common/doc/building.html#troubleshooting for assistance.

make[1]: *** [main] Error 2
make: *** [default] Error
```

I try to set slowdebug and fastdebug, always failure.

Comment: same issue on Mac 10.14.1 ...... Have you got a solution for this  ?

Comment: I think the problem fixed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50678467/building-openjdk-9-on-mac-os/54954805#54954805